# Regenerate keys in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

Just trying out Mongoid at the moment, I've run into an issue that's probably pretty simple but has me at a loss:

I have a really simple Article model:

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, :type => String
  field :content, :type => String

  key :title

  referenced_in :subject

  validates_presence_of :title
end
```

I added `key :title` after I had already created one test record. Newly created records work as expected, but the first Article (which originally had the normal mongoid object id) behaves strangely:

In rails views this first article still returns its object id instead of the new key. ie using `link_to article.name, article` returns:

```
<a href="/articles/4ef150970a68b38415000003">Show</a>
```

... when all the rest return the parameterized keys, like:

```
<a href="/articles/other-article">Show</a>
```

If I click that link I get "Record not found". I tried loading and resaving this record in the console, and after that calling `article.id` on that record did return the parameterized key, but it still shows up the old way in the view and doesn't work.

So, a couple questions:

1. What's going on here?
2. How do you fix it?
3. This situation indicates to me that if you set a field on a mongoid model to be the key, you need to be *really* sure that it will never change. How do you handle something like using the title of an article as a slug, then, when those may occasionally need change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since `_id` is immutable, your only option is to reinsert this document with your new 'sluggish' id and delete the old one.

And yes, _id format and shard key (if you use sharding) are the two things you better have right from the beginning :-)
Everything else can be fixed relatively easily.

Comment: So then, how would you setup "slugs" in Mongoid, so you can have human-friendly URLs but not break the system if someone needs to change a field that is logically part of the URL (and hence, the key)?

Comment: @Andrew I personally would leave `_id` alone, and would make it possible to find articles also by `slug` field (which would have unique index on).